# Probability that array remains the same after k swaps as per pseudocode in description

Tags: probability

Consider this pseudocode:
int arr[N];
for(int i=0;i

Comment: What do you mean by "k random swaps (distinct)"? What do you mean by distinct swap?

Comment: it is just choose two indices (which are distinct) and swap the elements in their positions.

Comment: So for example one may swap the elements at indices 3,4 as many times as one likes.

Comment: pseudo code is : choose k1 -> random between 0..n-1, k2 -> random between 0..n-1,(assume k1!=k2 or even like k1<k2) swap a[k1] with a[k2], repeat the above steps k times

Comment: One thing to note is that if $k$ is odd, then the probability must be zero.

Comment: I have reedited the question.